# Ajax alert function is not working with laravel data

Tags: ajax, laravel

i am trying to alert when i click on edit button, but it is not working in table.

**Ajax Code:**

```
  <script>
        $(function(){
    var $datasearch=$('#datasearch');
    $('#searchname').on('keyup', function(){
        $.get('/teachers/search/'+$(this).val(), function(teachers){
            $datasearch.empty();
            for (var i=0; i<teachers.length; i++){

                $datasearch.append('<tr>'
                +'<td>'+teachers[i].efirst+'</td>'+
                '<td>'+'<button class="btn btn-primary alert">edit</button>'+'</td>'
                +'</tr>');

            }
        });
    });
});
    </script>
```

**alert function:**

```
<script>
              $(document).ready(function(){
                $(".alert").click(function() {
                  alert("clicked");
                });
              });
</script>
```

Comment: The button does not exist in the DOM when the document is ready, the event listener is added before the button is appended

Comment: what should i change?

Comment: Listen to the append event and attach a click event listener to the button when it renders

Comment: ok, please add answer if possible

Comment: @CaddyDZ you are right, i am trying to search how to call function when it is required. as you suggested, if you can answer that would help too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following can be used to show an alert when clicking the edit button:

```
          $(document).ready(function(){
            $("body").on("click", ".alert", function() {
              alert("clicked");
            });
          });
```

Answer (score 0):

Best way to do it

**Add `onclick` attribute:**

```
$(function(){
    var $datasearch=$('#datasearch');
    $('#searchname').on('keyup', function(){
        $.get('/teachers/search/'+$(this).val(), function(teachers){
            $datasearch.empty();
            for (var i=0; i<teachers.length; i++){

                $datasearch.append('<tr>'
                +'<td>'+teachers[i].efirst+'</td>'+
                '<td>'+'<button class="btn btn-primary alert" onclick="clickfunction()">edit</button>'+'</td>'
                +'</tr>');

            }
        });
    });
});
```

Finally the DOM will be as:

```
<button class="btn btn-primary alert" onclick="clickfunction()">edit</button>
```

And write your function in script:

```
function clickfunction(){
     alert("clicked!");
     //Other code...
}
```